# Google pie chart no data show

Tags: php, google-pie-chart

[image]i am using google pie chart but in chart No data massage show but when i run query and
display it coming perfect but same query for data No data show, below the code
please help me,

while running same query it give perfect result but not in chart

```
<?php require 'connection.php';  ?>
<?php $query = 'SELECT SBU, count(RG) AS State from regionmaster group by SBU';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // echo $value['SBU'] . $value['State'];
    
    echo "['".$value['SBU']."',".$value['State']."],";
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Pic Chart</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['corechart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                <?php 
                while ($Chart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    echo "['".$Chart['SBU']."',".$Chart['State']."],";
                }

                ?>
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't manually create your json like that. It's very error prone. Fetch all data you need and put it in a PHP array and use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn it into real json. For example, the result you're currently getting has a trailing comma that shouldn't be there. You also can't iterate through the same result set twice when using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, so as long as you have the test code in the top, the chart will never get any data at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so can you give me the code, Thanks in advance